# How to add onclick event on Path(Path from Salesforce Lightning Design System)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am working on a Lightning web component and used path from Lightning Design System to show the value of the picklist field. I want to the change the value of picklist field by clicking on the other option available in path. I am creating path item dynamically in js using lwc:dom="manual" because the component should work on any object of salesforce.
Here is the code:
HTML :

```
<div class="pathComponent">
            <div class="slds-path">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-path__track">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-path__scroller-container">
                        <div class="slds-path__scroller">
                            <div class="slds-path__scroller_inner">
                                <ul class="slds-path__nav" role="listbox" aria-orientation="horizontal">

                                    <div class="pathPickVal" lwc:dom="manual" style="display:flex; width:100%"></div>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS :

```
const container = this.template.querySelector('.pathPickVal');
        let PathString = '';
        this.PicklistOptions.forEach(currentItem => {  //this.PicklistOptions has all the values available in the picklist
            if (currentItem == this.CurrentRecordPickVal) { //this.CurrentRecordPickVal have the value of picklist field
                PathString += `<li class="slds-path__item slds-is-current slds-is-active" role="presentation">
                <a aria-selected="true" class="slds-path__link" href="#" id="path-1"
                    role="option" tabindex="0">
                    <span class="slds-path__stage">
                        <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
                            <use
                                xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Current Stage:</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="slds-path__title">${currentItem}</span>
                </a>
            </li>`;
            } else {
                PathString += `<li class="slds-path__item slds-is-incomplete" role="presentation">
                <a aria-selected="false" class="slds-path__link" href="#" id="path-2"
                    role="option" tabindex="-1">
                    <span class="slds-path__stage">
                        <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
                            <use
                                xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check">
                            </use>
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="slds-path__title">${currentItem}</span>
                </a>
            </li>`;
            }
        }); //for loop ends


        container.innerHTML = PathString;

    }
```

I tried to add `onclick={changePickVale}` (changePickVale is some function) in else part in the `<li>` tag but that didn't work, whenever I click on any other options available the component kind a rerender automatically. So, how can i change the value of picklist field using path?

Comment: Huh, that's not what the lwc:dom=manual is for. You should look into compositing your component with multiple instances (look for "component composition").

Comment: Also, how are you trying to add this event to your `li` item?

Comment: `<li class="slds-path__item slds-is-incomplete" role="presentation" onclick={changePickVale}>`....in the else part of the for loop

Comment: @RenatoOliveira can you give some reference or example for Component Composition

Comment: Search on your favourite search engine for "component composition salesforce" and you'll find plenty of content about it. Adding the "onclick" event like you are doing with the dom being manually set on the page won't work. To make the event work with the manual dom you would probably have to use `addEventListener` to the list item element. That's a lot of work that you don't need to do if you use component composition.